# Installing xdebug with homebrew and php versions

Tags: php, apache, installation, homebrew, ini

I currently have 2 installations directories for php:

The one I am currently using at:

```
/etc/php.ini
```

Another one I installed later I guess?(long time ago, don't remember)

```
/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
```

So far what I've read I believe /etc/ directory to hold the original php files that come pre-installed with OSX. Correct my if I am wrong about this though.

Where exactly does the other installation come from?

Now I want to install xdebug with homebrew. I'm guessing a pre-requisite for this is having a PHP version already installed via homebrew?

If I were to let homebrew handle my PHP installation should I or do I need to remove my older PHP installation?

Thanks for reading and I you guys need more info from me, let me know.